# With only CSS can I make an element cover an entire DIV?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, exponent

To make it more simple, i'm working on this site  https://webdev02.amontagnana.it/ and on the 4th row we can see a text block and an embedded video.

I need to make the video's height just like the block on the left. (it has to be relative too because it has to be responsive to desktop and mobile)

Answer (score 0):

**Your site are loading and loading**
If you are cover an entire DIV . you need to fixed position and increase z-index as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add a custom class on **tatsu-column-inner** and add the background color black on it

[See the attached screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFvZE.png)